# Selecting objects by size in Cinema 4D

Tags: 3d, blender, mesh, 3d-modelling, cinema-4d

I have a mesh file containing a lot of objects, ranging from large to very small in size. I need to clean the file by removing all objects below a certain size or volume. Can someone please tell me how to select those objects automatically instead of me sifting through these manually?

I could also do this in Blender if that were easier but I'd still have no idea on how to do this as I'm no Blender user, I just do have access to it.